# SQL Server Report Services (SSRS), Access The properties of a Tablix from its Expresssion Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

While Using SQL Server Report Services (SSRS), I wanted to access the properties of a Tablix from its Expresssion Builder.  My Issue, Three are Three Tablix on the Page. I want to dynamically change the visibility of each tablix based of a parameter I pass to the report. e.g. I am passing the Parameter @ShowTablix with the value "Tablix1"
I expect Tablix1 to be visible while Tablix2 & Tablix3 are invisible.

Now i know a way how to do this.
In The Visibility.Hidden Property for the
Tablix I am setting the expression

=(Parameters!ShowTablix.Value<>"Tablix1")

I have to do this for each tablix so it becomes
for  Tablix2

=(Parameters!ShowTablix.Value<>"Tablix2")

and for Tablix3

=(Parameters!ShowTablix.Value<>"Tablix2")

**But I want to use something like this**

=(Parameters!ShowTablix.Value<>Me.Name)

i.e. a generic expression i can apply to all my tablixes **as is** .
any ideas?

by the way [ReportItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx)...=ReportItems("Textbox1").Value is only useful for [textboxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx)

Comment: Nope, I don't think there is any "generic" kind of self-reference that you can use in the expression builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the Tablix1 from the Property itself.

Right click and go to tablix properties and than change the **Name**. Or it can be done from the **Properties Window**.